# Postgresql work with time ranges, not datetime ranges

Tags: postgresql

Please advise how I can achieve simplicity working with time ranges in Postgresql. I want to perform queries like:

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM user_logs 
WHERE login_time_range BETWEEN '20:00' AND '02:00'
```

Note, I am not looking for `datetime` type. I am also aware of `tsrange` which does not suit my needs neither.

In the query above i want to store login_time_range as a range of starting and ending hour.

For example: `[01:00, 02:30)`

Later I wanna query to check weather login_time_range is falling into the range of the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Just create your own timerange type:

```
create type timerange as range (subtype = time);

create table user_logs
(
  ..., 
  login_time_range timerange
);
```

Then you can use all [range type operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html) on that column.

However, that will **not** properly deal with ranges that cross midnight like in your example 20:00 - 02:00.

A better way might be to use two columns: a start_time and a duration:

```
create table user_logs
(
  ..., 
  login_time time,
  login_duration interval
);
```

Then you can use the current date (or which ever you want) to detect the "midnight crossing:

```
select current_date + login_time as login_start_time, 
       current_date + login_time + duration as login_end_time
```